# Obtain a list of device wide active/installed device administrators

Tags: android, android-package-managers, device-admin, device-policy-manager, samsung-knox

Is there a way for an app to obtain a list of device wide active and installed device administrators?

DevicePolicyManager.getActiveAdmins() is able to get a list of active(enabled) device administrators, and PackageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers() is able to get a list of installed device administrators. However, they only get the list within their own user context. In a multi-user environment, they are unable to get the device-wide lists (tested on Android M on Nexus 5).

I ask because apparently in a Samsung Knox container, getActiveAdmins() returns a device-wide list (include the MyKnox agent), whereas queryBroadcastReceivers() returns the list within the container (tested on Android L on Galaxy S6 and Android M/N on Galaxy S7).

I understand Knox leverages on Android's multi-user feature to implement containers, but apparently there are some behavioral discrepancies between Android's multi-user and Knox containers. I would like to be able to get a legitimate list of active and installed device administrators from within a Knox container. Right now I'm getting that the MyKnox agent is active (via getActiveAdmins()) but yet not installed (via queryBroadcastReceivers()). This does not make sense.